# Counting documents with MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

This is a simplified version of my source data:

```
Cars    | Manual     | Petrol
1       | true       | true
2       | true       | false
3       | true       | true
4       | true       | true
5       | false      | true
6       | false      | true
```

I am trying to obtain this output:

```
Total cars: 6
Manual cars: 4
Petrol cars: 5
```

Is this possible in MongoDB using a single aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `db.yourColl.find({Manual:true}).count()` and `db.yourColl.find({Petrol:true}).count()`? With according indices, this should be a realtime query...

Comment: Are you saying that would be a more efficient way to do it?  Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the $group aggregation step and the $sum operator combined with $cond.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     $group: {
         _id: null, // we want to group into a single document
         "Total Cars": { $sum: 1 }, // all documents
         "Manual Cars": { 
             $sum : { 
                // add a "1" when Manual is true, otherwise add a "0"
                $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$Manual", true ] }
                    1,
                    0
                ] 
            } 
         },
         "Petrol Cars": { 
             $sum : { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$Petrol", true ] }
                    1,
                    0
                ] 
            } 
         }
     }
]);
```